# Iceweasel 26, no root privileges and ad blocking

Tags: root, adblock

In our workstations we don't have root privileges. Our home directories are synced (they don't depend on the physical computer). We have an old Iceweasel 26 installed.

I'd like to block the ads. Unfortunately, Adblock Plus is not compatible with Iceweasel 26. I'd use `/etc/hosts`, but, as far as I know, I can't set up user-specific /etc/hosts. I considered setting up my own local Firefox, but our home directory is limited to 768MB, so I don't think it's a good idea.

What would be an optimal solution in my case? Is taking an old version of ABP the only way out?

Comment: Regarding installing AdBlock Plus: can your admin install it globally for all users? I use Wheezy with the same version of Iceweasel, and AdBlock Plus from the official repo works fine here. The package is `xul-ext-adblock-plus`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of Adblock Plus you could use [uBlock origin](https://addons.mozilla.org/de/firefox/addon/ublock-origin/).

It is apparently usable with Firefox 24.0 and newer, so it should work with Iceweasel 26.

Answer (score 1):

While using /etc/hosts may not be the best solution, you *can* have a local hosts file by exporting the `HOSTALIASES` variable. Set it to `~/.hosts` or something. Take a look here:

http://blog.tremily.us/posts/HOSTALIASES/

Update: Just tested this on Debian Wheezy, works fine:

```
echo 'y www.yahoo.com' > ~/.hosts
export HOSTALIASES=~/.hosts
wget y
```

Comment: Well, I did `wget -O ~/.hosts http://winhelp2002.mvps.org/hosts.txt` then
`echo 'export HOSTALIASES=~/.hosts`, restarted the shell and tried
`host www.winaproduct.com`. The name is properly resolved instead of giving `0.0.0.0`

Comment: The first saves the file into ~/.hosts. And in the second, indeed, I forgot the end: `echo 'export HOSTALIASES=~/.hosts' >> .bashrc`